# How could we sleep when we are executing a syscall that execute in interrupt mode

Tags: c, exception, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

When I am executing a system call to do write or something else, the ISR corresponded to the exception is executing in interrupt mode (on cortex-m3 the IPSR register is having a non-zero value, 0xb). And what I have learned is that when we execute a code in an interrupt mode we can not sleep, we can not use functions that might block ...

My question is that: is there any kind of a mechanism with which the ISR could still executing in interrupt mode and in the same time it could use functions that might block, or is there any kind of trick is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This is more of a comment than an answer but is too big to fit in a comment or series of comments.

**TL;DR:** Needing to `sleep` or execute a *blocking* operation from an ISR is a fundamental misdesign. This seems like an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Doing `sleep` [even in application code] is generally a code smell. Why do you feel you *need* to sleep [vs. some event/completion driven mechanism]?

Please *edit* your question and add clarification [i.e. *don't* just add comments]

> When I am executing a system call to do write or something else

What is your *application* doing? A `write` to *what* device? What "something else"?

What is the architecture/board, kernel/distro? (e.g. Raspberry Pi running Raspian? nvidia Jetson? Beaglebone? Xilinx FPGA with petalinux?)

What is the H/W device and where did the device driver come from? Did you write the device driver yourself or is it a standard one that comes with the kernel/distro? If *you* wrote it, please post it in your question.

Is the device configured properly? (e.g.) Are the DTB entries correct?

Is the device a *block* device, such as a disk controller? Or, is it a *character* device, such as a UART? Does the device transfer data via DMA? Or, does it transfer data by reading/writing to/from an IO port?

What do *you* mean by "exception"? Generally, exception is an abnormal condition (e.g. segfault, bus error, etc.). Please describe the *exact* context/scenario for which this occurs.

Generally, an ISR does little things. (e.g.) Grab [and save] status from the device. Clear/rearm the interrupt in the interrupt controller. Start the next queued transfer request. Wake up the sleeping base level task (usually the task that executed the syscall [waiting on a completion event in kernel mode]).

More elaborate actions are generally deferred and handled in the interrupt's "bottom half" handler and/or *tasklet*. Or, the base level is woken up and *it* handles the remaining processing.

What kernel subsystems are involved? Are you using platform drivers? Are you interfacing from within the DMA device driver framework? Are message buses involved (e.g. I2C, SPI, etc.)?

Interrupt and device handling in the linux kernel is somewhat different than what one might do in a "bare metal" system or RTOS (e.g. `FreeRTOS`). So, if you're coming from those environments, you'll need to think about restructuring your driver code [and/or application code].

What are your requirements for device *throughput* and *latency*?

You may wish to consult a good book on linux device driver design. And, you may wish to consult the kernel's `Documentation` subdirectory.

If you're able to provide more information, I may be able to help you further.

---

**UPDATE:**

> A system call is not really in the same class as a hardware interrupt as far as the kernel is concerned, even if the CPU hardware uses the same sort of exception vector mechanisms for handling both hardware and software interrupts. The kernel treats the system call as a transition from user mode to kernel mode. – Ian Abbott

This is a succinct/great explanation. The "mode" or "context" has little to do with *how* we got/get there from a H/W mechanism.

The CPU doesn't really "understand" interrupt mode [as defined by the kernel]. It understands "supervisor" vs "user" *privilege* level [sometimes called "mode"].

When executing at user privilege level, an interrupt/exception will notice the transition from "user" level to "supvervisor" level. It may have a special register that specifies the address of the [initial] supervisor stack pointer. Atomically, it swaps in the value, pushing the user SP onto the new kernel stack.

If the interrupt is interrupting a CPU that is already at supervisor level, the existing [supervisor] SP will be used unchanged.

Note that `x86` has privilege "ring" levels. User mode is ring 3 and the highest [most privileged] level is ring 0. For `arm`, some arches can have a "hypervisor" privilege level [which is higher privilege than "supervisor" privilege].

The setup of the mode/context is handled in `arch/arm/kernel/entry-*.S` code.

An `svc` is a *synchronous* interrupt [generated by a special CPU instruction]. The resulting context is the context of the currently executing thread. It is analogous to "call function in kernel mode". The resulting context is "*kernel* thread mode". At that point, it's not terribly useful to think of it as an "interrupt" anymore.

In fact, on some arches, the syscall instruction/mechanism doesn't use the interrupt vector table. It may have a fixed address or use a "call gate" mechanism (e.g. `x86`).

Each thread has its own stack which is different than the initial/interrupt stack.

Thus, once the entry code has established the context/mode, it is *not* executing in "interrupt mode". So, the full range of kernel functions *is* available to it.

An interrupt from a H/W device is *asynchronous* [may occur at any time the CPU's internal interrupt enable flag is set]. It may interrupt a userspace application [executing in application mode] OR kernel thread mode OR an existing ISR executing in interrupt mode [from another interrupt]. The resulting ISR is executing in "interrupt mode" or "ISR mode".

Because the ISR can interrupt a kernel thread, it may *not* do certain things. For example, if the CPU were in [kernel] thread mode, and it was in the middle of a `kmalloc` call [`GFP_KERNEL`], the ISR would see partial state and any action that tried to adjust the kernel's heap would result in corruption of the heap.

This is a design choice by linux for speed.

Kernel ISRs may be classified as "fast interrupts". The ISR executes with the CPU interrupt enable [IE] flag cleared. No normal H/W interrupt may interrupt the ISR.

So, if another H/W device asserts its interrupt request line [in the external interrupt controller], that request will be "pending". That is, the request line has been asserted but the CPU has not acknowledged it [and the CPU has *not* jumped via the interrupt table].

The request will remain pending until the CPU allows further interrupts by asserting IE. Or, the CPU may clear the pending interrupt *without* taking action by clearing the pending interrupt in the interrupt controller.

For a "slow" interrupt ISR, the interrupt entry code will clear the interrupt in the external interrupt controller. It will then rearm interrupts by setting IE and call the ISR. This ISR *can* be interrupted by other [higher priority] interrupts. The result is a "stacked" interrupt.

> I have been searching all over the places, I come to the conclusion is that the interrupts have a higher priority than some of exceptions in the Linux kernel.

An exception [synchronous interrupt] can be interrupted if the IE flag is enabled. An `svc` is treated differently but after the entry code is executed, the IE flag is set, so the actual syscall code [executing in kernel thread mode] can be interrupted by a H/W interrupt.

Or, in limited circumstances, the kernel code can generate an exception (e.g. a page fault caused by a *kernel* action [which is usually deemed fatal]).

> but I am still looking on how exactly the context switching happen when executing an exception and letting the processor to execute in a thread mode while the SVCall exception is pending (was preempted and have not returned yet)... I think when I understand that, it would be more clear to me.

I think you have to be very careful with the terminology. In particular, when combining terms from disparate sources. Although user mode, kernel thread mode, or interrupt mode can be considered a context [in the dictionary sense of the word], context *switching* usually means that the current thread is suspended, the scheduler selects a new thread to run and resumes it. That is separate from the user-to-kernel transition.

> And if there is any recommended resources about that for ARM-Cortex-M3/4, it would be nice

Here is something: https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/arm-cortex-m-exceptions-and-nvic But, be very careful in applying the terminology therein. What it considers "pending" only exists in the kernel during the entry code. What is more relevant is what the *kernel* does to set up mode/context and the terms are not equivalent.

So, from the kernel's standpoint, it's probably better to *not* consider an `svc` as "pending".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, correct me if i am wrong, I think the kind of the syscall is irrelevant because any syscall might block the process (put it to the wait queue and then call schedule function) for example: the kmalloc function with the GFB_KERNEL flag is specified might block the process if it would swap some pages, and when we write code for device driver we usually use kamlloc to allocate memory in function is nested from the corresponding syscall... the architecture is armv7, the micro-architecture is cortex-m3... I mean by exception synchronous event, syscall cause an excepthion

Comment: on in ARMv7 the SVCall is an exception when user-program want execute a syscall he use svc instruction, so the corresponding ISR would be invoked in interrupt mode

Comment: (on cortex-m3 the IPSR register is having a non-zero value, 0xb), my question is that in interrupt mode we are not allowed to use functions that might sleep, for example if we want to use kmalloc we have to specify GFP_ATOMIC but the when executing a syscall we are allowed to sleep, which is also execute in interrupt mode not in thread mode.

Comment: @masalkhi A system call is not really in the same class as a hardware interrupt as far as the kernel is concerned, even if the CPU hardware uses the same sort of exception vector mechanisms for handling both hardware and software interrupts. The kernel treats the system call as a transition from user mode to kernel mode.

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks for your answer, I have been searching all over the places, I come to the conclusion is that the interrupts have a higher priority than some of exceptions in the Linux kernel. but I am still looking on how exactly the context switching happen when executing an exception and letting the processor to execute in a thread mode while the SVCall exception is pending (was preempted and have not returned yet)... I think when I understand that, it would be more clear to me. And if there is any recommended resources about that for ARM-Cortex-M3/4, it would be nice

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you for the information and for the resource.